# Class Constructor Misinterpreted

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, c++20, c++-modules

The constructor argument below is misinterpreted as a `const int` by Visual Studio 2019's Intellisense and I'm given an error. I am using the C++ Preview (C++ 20) and modules. Compiling is successful. Am I maybe missing something? There might be a key detail about modules I'm missing.

```cpp
Bar(const Foo foo)
    : foo(foo)
{
}
```

https://github.com/Karutoh/MinimalExamples/tree/master/MisinterpretedConstructor

[image]

Comment: Intellisense isn't perfect, the best you can do is raise a bug report with Microsoft. Include a [mre]

Comment: Unfortunately I have. It was quickly dismissed and closed. Although there was an error in my code before where I used `export import moduleIdentifierHere;`. Which for whatever reason seemed to work. Maybe that's a Clang thing.
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/C-Module-Class-Constructors/1281602

Comment: If you can make a [mre] as text not screenshots you might have more success with your next bug report

Comment: I have now provided a minimal example. It seems objects are not read correctly as arguments, and are misinterpreted as `const int`.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it seems a issue. I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.